# Определить число узлов на каждом уровне дерева

Tags: c++, visual-c++, дерево

Помогите определить число узлов на каждом уровне дерева.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int info;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
} *tree;

void Add(int a, Node **tree) {
    if ((*tree) == NULL) {
        (*tree) = new Node; 
        (*tree)->info = a;
        (*tree)->left = (*tree)->right = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if (a > (*tree)->info) {
        Add(a, &(*tree)->right);
    } else {
        Add(a, &(*tree)->left);
    }
}

void Print(Node *tree) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    cout << tree->info << endl;
    Print(tree->left);
    Print(tree->right);
}


int main() {
    int n;
    int info;
    cout << "Enter number of elements: "; cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << " elements: "; cin >> info;
        Add(info, &tree);
    }
    cout << "Tree: " << endl;
    Print(tree);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что у вас собственно не получается? Сформулируйте проблему/вопрос.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей функции `Print` добавьте (или перепишите, написав новую функцию) уровень глубины, и при обходе дерева сохраняйте результаты. Я бы делал с помощью `map`, примерно так:

```
void Count(Node* tree, map<int,int>&m, int level)
{
    m[level]++;
    if (tree->left)  Count(tree->left,m,level+1);
    if (tree->right) Count(tree->right,m,level+1);
}

map<int,int> m;
Count(tree,m,0);
for(auto i: m)
{
    cout << "На уровне " << i.first << " находится " << i.second << "узлов.\n";
}
```

Comment: есть ошибки в функции declaration is incompatible with "<error-type Count">

Comment: @Neon  http://ideone.com/dntPJJ - где?

Comment: в первой строке

Comment: @Neon Еще раз - я привел ссылку на полный код, скомпилированный, отработавший. Смотрите, что у вас не так - может, вы в чем-то опечатались при переносе? Еще раз - здесь: http://ideone.com/dntPJJ - полностью скомпилированная и выполненная программа.